# How to fetch all videos in custom page which uploaded in wp-admin (Media) in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to fetch all videos which are uploaded in back end wp-admin media. 
how to show all videos or audios in custom page which i uploaded in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

```
 get_children('order=ASC&orderby=menu_order&post_type=attachment&post_parent=' . $post->ID);
```

This will return you the attachment attached with the current post on which you are standing right now.

Comment: Dear Moeed Farooqui, Actually I added lots of videos in media. now I'd like to show those all videos in one template page not a current post attachment/video.

Comment: make a page named template-xyz.php here `xyz` will be your template name.so all the listings of videos will be shown there

Comment: I have done by wordpress function. 
$args = array
    (
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'video',
        'numberposts' => -1
    );
 $audiofiles = get_posts($args);

 foreach ($audiofiles as $file)
 {
      $url = wp_get_attachment_url($file->ID);
      echo $url; // url
      
 }

Do you have any other option to do this ?